# django uwsgi - nginx restart after reboot not working

Tags: python, linux, django, nginx, debian

my django site is running under debian, nginx + uwsgi. I made nginx restartable after server reboot by following this hint: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/ubuntu-and-debian-adding-an-nginx-init-script

but sometimes, my nginx doesnot start after a reboot and I need to restart it manuelly in shell. Uwsgi daemon is inside rc.local file.

Server is Debian wheezy. what am I missing? what should I do so that nginx restarts always after system reboot?

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is supposed to start by default. Try the following to check if the start/stop links for nginx service exists.

`sudo update-rc.d nginx start 20 2 3 4 5 . 80 0 1 6 .`

This is saying start Nginx with priority 20 on run levels 2 3 4 5 and stop it with priority 80 on run levels 0 1 6. Note the dots used in the sample code, they terminate the argument input.